# Passing an array of variable length to a class method

Tags: php, arrays, methods

I am trying to create a little MVC framework for myself and am using a url structure similar to: `http://www.example.com/className/methodName/var1/var2/var3`.  I want to make it able to accomodate for any number of variables.

I have all of the information how I need it, except for the `/var1/var2/var3` part.  Currently I have it in an array exploded() upon the "/", so: `var[0] = "var1",var[1] = "var2",var[2] = "var3"`

Since the method which will be called will be unknown and each method can require a different amount parameters I want to figure out a way to be able to pass the parameters as:

```
$controller->$function($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

rather than

```
$controller->$function($var);
```

I realize I can string together a comma delimited variable such as `$var1, $var2, $var3` and use eval() to do what I want, but I am wondering if there is a better way to go about it.  I would rather not use eval() for this as it will be using user submitted data.

Worst case scenario, I figure I would just try to cleanse the data before the eval, but I'd still like to avoid it.

One other potential Idea I had was to use a foreach() and loop through each element inside of the the method call.  But even that seems a little messy to me.

On a side note, is the standard way to pass a variable amount of parameters to group them together in an array and pass in a single parameter?

If anyone knows of a more elegant way to do this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $function), array($var1, $var2...));
```

Comment: Agreed.  Also worth looking at overloading / magic methods in PHP.  Specifically: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: have you actually read the manual page to which you linked to ?

Comment: I've fixed the arguments, (I think it was a typo).

Comment: @tereško, I'm sorry, but what did I miss? (Except the thing Wouter fixed.)

Answer (score 1):

@Dogbert's answer would complement what I'm about to suggest.

You could create a function that accepts no parameters and you're free to pass as many parameters (or no parameters at all), you'll only have to use PHP functions like: `func_get_args()`, `func_num_args()` and `func_get_arg(int arg_index)` to do your manipulation.

An Example follows below:

```
function syncOrderRelation(){
    $num_arguments = func_num_args();
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    #gets all the arguments in the request
    list($userID,$spID,$productID) = $arguments;
    #if you know what you're expecting or
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_arguments; $i++){
            $argument_at_index = func_get_arg($i);
    }
}
```

You could call this function in the following ways:

```
syncOrderRelation();
syncOrderRelation($var1,$var2,var3);
syncOrderRelation($var1);
#or you could call it as @Dogbert suggested since the function will accept whatever
#arguments you supply
```

The rest is up to you...Happy coding!